# Why isn't my youtube embed loading in fancybox?

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

Here is the [link](http://nicolaelvin.com/authoring/other_stuff.php) to the page, it's the last item on that page.  Below is my html.  The other fancyboxes are working, just seems to eb an issue with this one.

```
<a href='http://www.youtube.com/embed/NXzSX5Cbebw' class='fancybox everybody_is_smoking_video'>
     <img src='phpThumb/phpThumb.php?src=../images/smokingvideo_thumbnail.png&h=189&w=240' alt='thumbnail ofeverybody_is_smoking_video'/>
</a>
```

My js

```
$('.everybody_is_smoking_video').fancybox({
            'height': 423,
            'width':579, 
            'titlePosition': 'inside',
            'href' : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
            'type'      : 'swf',
            'swf'       : {'wmode':'transparent','allowfullscreen':'true'}

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because it is a different domain.

Change the type to 'iframe'. That should do the trick. I went and did it with firebug and it worked fine.

Since I was just running it in the console, I had to remove the href part in the fancybox config. But without it it still worked fine.